# How to align navbar with logo?

Tags: html, css

I am new to all this. I cant align the navbar with the logo because for some reason margin-top/ bottom don't seem to work.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div class="nav_header" "nav">
        <ul>
            <img src="assets/logo2.png" class='title'>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</BODY>
```

Here is CSS code

```
body {
    background-image: url('assets/bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}    

a:link, a:visited {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.nav_header {
    height: 60px;
    background: #000000 left no-repeat;
}

.title {
    margin-left: 80px;
}


li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 20;
    float: none; 
}
```

Comment: For valid HTML, you need to wrap any elements inside a ul or ol with li's. Also, your class "nav" is not inside your class attribute - both nav_head and nav should be within the same quotations marks. Can you also post a jsfiddle with the full HTML?

Comment: Its considered good practice to not capitalize your html tags.

Comment: Do you want to put logo in the same line with menu ?

Comment: @Dima yes, i want those to be in the same line.

Comment: @Prusprus fixed the nav's attributes, but still no change. for some reason i can push lis left and right, but not up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should look like this:

```
<div class="nav_header" "nav">
<div class="logo">
 <img src="assets/logo2.png" class='title'>  
 </div>
<ul>

<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>    
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

add css:

```
.nav_header ul, .nav_header ul li, .nav_header .logo {
float: left;
}
```

it very recommended to set height and width to div that wrap image.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your image in `<li></li>` tags and then manage the image dimensions.

Comment: tried just now, still, the links are far below the logo

Comment: better you create a fiddle and paste the link here

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the he `<img />` tag outside your `<ul><ul>` but still inside your `<div><div>`  and then float the `<li><li>` and the image left.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of guessing what you actually want to achieve...
You can use [CSS vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) :

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Then you can also use `margin-bottom` to further align them if you want.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uakp416r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

add img in `<li>` tag

```css
a:link, a:visited {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.nav_header {
    height: 60px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    display:block;
}

.title {
    margin-left: 80px;
}


li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: none; 
}

li img {
  border:10px solid #333;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_header">
<ul>
<li><img src="assets/logo2.png" class='title'></li>
<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLecth7t/1/):

```
<div class="nav_header nav">
    <img src="https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/wordpress-logo-32-blue.png" class="title" height="32" width="32" />    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.nav_header {
    height: 34px;
    padding:13px 0 13px 20px;
    background: #000000 left no-repeat;
}

.nav_header > ul, 
.nav_header > img{display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin:0; padding: 0;}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-size: 20;
}
```

Semantically you'll want to pull your image out of your unordered list. If you set both `img` and `ul` as inline-blocks, you can align themselves to eachother. I've vertically centered both image and navigation to your header by compensating the nav's height for some padding (top and bottom).

A few notes about your above code:

- The only elements that can be direct descendents of `ul` and `ol` are `li`. If you want to add an `img` to a list, it has to be included within a `li`.
- Multiple classes need to be inluced within the same double quotations, see `nav_header` and `nav`.
- Always declare your `height` and `width` attributes on your image tags.
- Keep a certain standard when writing HTML in regards to using single our double quotations for your attribute value (see `title` class) and uppercase and lowercase HTML tags.